# Does spring-boot-configuration-processor process annotated bean methods?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Does `spring-boot-configuration-processor` process annotated bean methods?
Because in my case, it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
@Data
public class DatasourceConnectionPoolProperties {
  private Integer initialSize;
  private Integer maxIdle;
  private Integer minIdle;
  private Integer timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis;
  private Integer minEvictableIdleTimeMillis;
  private Boolean testOnBorrow;
  private String validationQuery;
}
```

And somewhere in @Configuration-annotated class:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("persistence.pool")
protected DatasourceConnectionPoolProperties localPoolProperties() {
  return new DatasourceConnectionPoolProperties();
}
```

During compilation, no metadata generated. But, when `DatasourceConnectionPoolProperties` gets annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` metadata generated.

Did I make mistake somewhere, or it's just `spring-boot-configuration-processor` limitations?

Comment: your method must be `public`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does but the annotation processor only looks for `public` method and yours is `protected` (which is very unusual for a `@Bean` method by the way).